# Running BrowserStack locally using Selenium causes System.Exception while executing BrowserStackLocal start

Tags: c#, .net, browserstack

I am trying to connect from Visual Studio 2015 to local BrowserStack to run my applications on a remote server and I have updated this in App.Config file as below. I managed to run them in parallel on BrowserStack cloud using public URL's, but I couldn't make my tests running locally.

```
<add key="build" value="specflow-browserstack" />
<add key="name" value="local_test" />
<add key="browserstack.debug" value="true" />
<add key="browserstack.local" value="true" />
<add key="browserstack.localIdentifier" value="Test123" />
```

And also when I launch browserstack local on browser using Chrome addon then I am seeing below error and my test is not running

```
System.Exception: Eror while executing BrowserStackLocal start 
{"state":"disconnected","pid":6312,"message":"Disconnected"}
at BrowserStack.BrowserStackTunnel.<>c__DisplayClass17_0.
```

Comment: Have you tried running their sample repo for specflow: https://github.com/browserstack/specflow-browserstack? Also, not sure how this relates to Chrome Add on

Comment: I tried but that one is also throwing same exception at line browserStackLocal.start(bsLocalArgs);

Answer (score 1):

I Was able to solve this by below piece of code

```
private Process browserStackLocal;
if (capability.GetCapability("browserstack.local") != null && capability.GetCapability("browserstack.local").ToString() == "true") { 
browserStackLocal = Process.Start(@"E:\BrowserStackLocal-win32\BrowserStackLocal.exe", "--key 8EqNTv4J2C******"); Thread.Sleep(30000); }

public void Cleanup() { driver.Quit(); if (browserStackLocal != null) { browserStackLocal.Kill(); } }
```

Comment: I just tried to run the BrowserStackLocal.exe locally . it's just a work around